# Clasp Login over Corporate Proxy

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

Iam reading article about **[Command Line Interface using clasp]** (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp) .-
I can install clasp via npm over corporate proxy with user/pass ...

But, when i want use :

> clasp login

it returns:

> Error: Looks like you are offline.

Anyone can say me why look like offline if npm work well?

Comment: Have you tried checking the network connection first?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to login without localhost to bypass the proxy.

```
clasp login --no-localhost
```

Docs: https://github.com/google/clasp#login

---

Perhaps we should state that rather than being "offline", we are unable to reach the Apps Script API and suggest this workaround.